# Blender Python get FCurve from Polygon (Change interpolation mode of material_index)

Tags: python, animation, css-animations, polygon, blender

My goal is to animate the material_index of a face, which kind of works already. The problem is, that with my current approach, keyframes might overlap and then things get messy.

```
p.material_index = default_mat_index
p.keyframe_insert("material_index", frame=frame_on - 1)
p.material_index = color_index
p.keyframe_insert("material_index", frame=frame_on)
p.keyframe_insert("material_index", frame=frame_off)
p.material_index = default_mat_index
p.keyframe_insert("material_index", frame=frame_off + 1)
```

So what I'm trying to do now is to change the interpolation mode to `CONSTANT` and only use this:

```
p.material_index = color_index
p.keyframe_insert("material_index", frame=frame_on)
p.material_index = default_mat_index
p.keyframe_insert("material_index", frame=frame_off)
```

I used this code before, to change the interpolation mode of keyframes:

```
fcu = bpy.data.actions.get(o.animation_data.action.name).fcurves.find("material_index", index=1)
for pt in fcu.keyframe_points:
    pt.interpolation = "CONSTANT"
```

But the polygon doesn't have no `animation_data` and the object, which the polygon is a part of, doesn't have a `"material_index"`-fcurve.